# JS Specific ending date calculator

Tags: javascript, date

If I have a starting date of 31st of January and I add 1 month, it returns a date of 2nd of March.
I am trying to make a script that will add months to date in this way :

```
starting date : 31/01/2000
+1 month = 29/02/2000
+2 months = 31/03/2000
+3 months = 30/04/2000 
....
+12 months = 28/02/2001
```

Another case :

```
Starting date : 28/02/2001
+1 month : 31/03/2001
+2 months : 30/04/2001
...
```

So, the idea is if starting date is the last day of the current month, ending date must be the last day of month.

> So, my code logic is below :
>
> var date = new Date(2017,01,30);
>   1. Get current day of this date. (x)
>   2. If x < days in this month, add 1 month to date
>      2.1 In same if, If modified date < x, set date to last day of previous month
>   3. Else of main if, set date to last day of next month

My JSFiddle is here : https://jsfiddle.net/5mfLo8zs/
Idk what is wrong in syntax, but it gives me a .getDate() is not a function error, probably, it's not the unique problem.

P.S. I know that this theme is duplicated, I took 10 minutes to search for identic question, but I found just how to set last day of month, but here I need something more.

Comment: Try this: `var endDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth() +2, 0)`. **[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5mfLo8zs/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Check if date passed is the last day of the month?

  1. If yes, you will need to add 1 to months. This is because, logic to get last day of month works by creating a date as 1st day of next month and then subtract 1.
- Now initialize a temp variable that will hold value of day. Set it to 0 by default.
- If months are same, set this temp variable to passed date's day. Else let it be 0.
- Now you have all the parameters to create new date. Return it. Note, updating same date variable will override original value. So try to avoid any manipulations to it.

```js
function addMonths(date, months) {
  var d = 0;
  var next = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 1);
  if (next.getMonth() === date.getMonth()) {
    d = date.getDate()
  }
  else{
    months++
  }

  // use following line in actual code.
  // return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + months, d)
  // This line is just fror demonstration purpose.
  return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + months, d).toDateString();
}

console.log(addMonths(new Date(2017, 0, 31), 1));
console.log(addMonths(new Date(2017, 0, 31), 3));
console.log(addMonths(new Date(2017, 0, 15), 3));
console.log(addMonths(new Date(2016, 11, 31), 1));
console.log(addMonths(new Date(2016, 11, 11), 1));
```